# How does evaluation of a thunk object work?

Tags: scheme, lazy-evaluation, sicp, thunk

[This](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node86.html) chapter in SICP says that the definition of `actual-value` for extracting a thunk's real value is this:

```
(define (actual-value exp env)
  (force-it (eval exp env)))
```

But what if `exp` itself is a thunk? Based on the definition of `delay-it` it would mean that it is a list object of the form `(list 'thunk exp env)`. The [eval](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node77.html) function however is in no way prepared for handling tagged lists beginning with 'thunk. Why doesn't eval produce an error due to the unmatched cond expression?

**Edit:**
I think evaluating the following expression should result in an error:

```
(define (add a) (+ 2 a))
(add 0)
```

`add` is a compound procedure, therefore `delay-it` is performed on its arguments before it being applied. `+` is a primitive produce, which means that `actual-value` will be called on its arguments. The arguments are 2 and a. a is a thunk object, therefore `actual-value` should produce an error when it passes it to `eval`, because `eval` does not have a cond case which deals with lists tagged with 'thunk.

Comment: can you provide an example of actual code where this situation occurs? I have a hunch that it can't happen in practice, by construction

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: I have added an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point here is that when we're evaluating `(+ 2 a)` the `a` is not a thunk, it's just a symbol that will be looked up in the environment, and whose value is a thunk. And after `eval` returns the thunk, `force-it` will take care of forcing its value. Let's step through the process.

The only argument that gets delayed in your example is the `0`, at the time of invoking `add`, but even so that value will get forced *eventually* by `list-of-arg-values` - think of it, at some point all the procedure applications will lead to `apply-primitive-procedure`, and that's the point where we force the thunks.

If we perform a trace at the time of calling `list-of-arg-values`, the values passed to `actual-value` are `2` and `a` in that order. The `2` just evaluates to itself, no problem there. Let's see what happens with the `a`; this snippet in `actual-value`:

```
(eval exp env)
```

... will receive the symbol `a` as its `exp` (a variable), returning the associated thunk after looking it up in the environment (remember: when we extended the environment in `apply`, we created bindings between variables and thunks), and after that `force-it` will receive a thunk as the result of calling `eval`:

```
(force-it (eval exp env)))
```

... and `force-it` *knows* how to evaluate the thunk, in the `(thunk? obj)` case. And that's it! finally we obtain `0`, the actual value.

Comment: I completely forgot that `actual-value` receives `a` as a symbol. Thank you for the awesome explanation!